# Longest slice of a binary array that can be split into two parts

Tags: algorithm

how to find longest slice of a binary array that can be split into two parts: in the left part, 0 should be the leader; in the right part, 1 should be the leader ?
for example :
[1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1] should return 7  so that the first part is [1,0,1,0,0] and the second part is [1,1]

i tried the following soln and it succeeds in some test cases but i think it is not efficient:

```
  public static int solution(int[] A)
        {
            int length = A.Length;
            if (length <2|| length>100000)
                return 0;
            if (length == 2 && A[0] != A[1])
                return 0;
            if (length == 2 && A[0] == A[1])
                return 2;
            int zerosCount = 0;
            int OnesCount = 0;
            int start = 0;
            int end = 0;
            int count=0;

            //left hand side
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                end = i;
                if (A[i] == 0)
                    zerosCount++;
                if (A[i] == 1)
                    OnesCount++;
                count = i;
                if (zerosCount == OnesCount )
                {
                    start++;
                    break;
                }

            }

            int zeros = 0;
            int ones = 0;

            //right hand side
            for (int j = end+1; j < length; j++)
            {
                count++;
                if (A[j] == 0)
                    zeros++;
                if (A[j] == 1)
                    ones++;
                if (zeros == ones)
                {
                    end--;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

I agree brute force is time complexity: O(n^3).

But this can be solved in linear time. I've implemented it in C, here is the code:

```
int f4(int* src,int n)
{
    int i;
    int sum;
    int min;
    int sta;
    int mid;
    int end;

    // Find middle
    sum = 0;
    mid = -1;
    for (i=0 ; i<n-1 ; i++)
    {
        if (src[i]) sum++;
        else sum--;

        if (src[i]==0 && src[i+1]==1)
        {
            if (mid==-1 || sum<min)
            {
                min=sum;
                mid=i+1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (mid==-1) return 0;

    // Find start
    sum=0;
    for (i=mid-1 ; i>=0 ; i--)
    {
        if (src[i]) sum++;
        else sum--;

        if (sum<0) sta=i; 
    }

    // Find end
    sum=0;
    for (i=mid ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        if (src[i]) sum++;
        else sum--;

        if (sum>0) end=i+1; 
    }

    return end-sta;
}
```

This code is tested: brute force results vs. this function. They have same results. I tested all valid arrays of 10 elements (1024 combinations).

If you liked this answer, don't forget to vote up :)

Answer (score 3):

As promissed, heres the update:

I've found a simple algorithm with linear timecomplexity to solve the problem.

The math:
Defining the input as int[] bits, we can define this function:

```
f(x) = {bits[x] = 0: -1; bits[x] = 1: 1}
```

Next step would be to create a basic integral of this function for the given input:

```
F(x) = bits[x] + F(x - 1)
F(-1) = 0
This integral is from 0 to x.
```

`F(x)` simply represents the number of `count(bits , 1 , 0 , x + 1) - count(bits , 0 , 0 , x + 1)`. This can be used to define the following function: `F(x , y) = F(y) - F(x)`, which would be the same as `count(bits , 1 , x , y + 1) - count(bits , 0 , x , y + 1)` (number of 1s minus number of 0s in the range [x , y] - this is just to show how the algorithm basically works).

Since the searched sequence of the field must fulfill the following condition: in the range `[start , mid]` 0 must be leading, and in the range `[mid , end]` 1 must be leading and `end - start + 1` must be the biggest possible value, the searched `mid` must fulfill the following condition: `F(mid) < F(start) AND F(mid) < F(end)`. So first step is to search the minimum of 'F(x)', which would be the mid (every other point must be > than the minimum, and thus will result in a smaller / equally big range `[end - start + 1]`. NOTE: this search can be optimized by taking into the following into account: `f(x)` is always either `1` or `-1`. Thus, if `f(x)` returns 1bits for the next `n` steps, the next possible index with a minimum would be `n * 2` ('n' 1s since the last minimum means, that 'n' -1s are required afterwards to reach a minimum - or atleast 'n' steps).

Given the 'x' for the minimum of `F(x)`, we can simply find `start` and `end` (biggest/smallest value b, s ∈ [0 , length(bits) - 1] such that: `F(s) > F(mid)` and `F(b) > F(mid)`, which can be found in linear time.

Pseudocode:

```
input: int[] bits
output: int

//input verification left out

//transform the input into F(x)
int temp = 0;
for int i in [0 , length(bits)]
    if bits[i] == 0
         --temp;
    else
         ++temp;

//search the minimum of F(x)
int midIndex = -1
int mid = length(bits)
for int i in [0 , length(bits - 1)]
    if bits[i] > mid
         i += bits[i] - mid //leave out next n steps (see above)
    else if bits[i - 1] > bits[i] AND bits[i + 1] > bits[i]
         midIndex = i
         mid = bits[i]

if midIndex == -1
    return //only 1s in the array


//search for the endindex    
int end
for end in [length(bits - 1) , mid]
    if bits[end] > mid
        break
    else
        end -= mid - bits[end] //leave out next n searchsteps

//search for the startindex
int start
for start in [0 , mid]
    if bits[start] > mid
         break
    else
         start += mid - bits[start]

 return end - start
```